# Undefined method `level` for Mongoid logger in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm seeing this:

```
undefined method `level' for #<Mongoid::Logger:0xcd1a1f>
```

When I set the Mongoid logger in my init. The logger is being set by trivial means:

```
Mongoid.logger = Logger.new($stdout)
```

in global.rb

What is the issue here? How do I get Mongoid to log to my own logger so I can see some queries?

I've also tried to not avail:

```
Mongoid.logger = Logger.new($stdout, :info)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest build is broken:

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid
http://travis-ci.org/#!/mongoid/mongoid/builds/722676

You will have to wait till they fix it or use an older version

Edit: Ok I was having the same problem and I solved it by doing this:

1) Set the specific version you want for mongoid gem in your Gemfile

```
gem 'mongoid', '= 2.4.5'
```

2) install

```
$ bundle install
```

3) restart your server

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here may be where you are initiating the `Mongoid.logger` and how you are doing it. In my `Rails 3.2` app running `Ruby 1.9.2` with `Mongoid 2.4.3` I have no problem instantiating the `Mongoid Logger`.

Here you can read the [Mongoid Configuration](http://mongoid.org/docs/rails/railties.html) that shows how to setup the logger.

The code from my most recent app to instantiate the logger in `Application.rb` found in the `/config` folder

```
module Application_Name
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    config.mongoid.logger = Logger.new($stdout)
```